# Central potential vs non central potential (particle in a box)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation

Whenever we are given a central force potential, we keen to investigate how the energy levels are related to the Angular Momentum operator like $L_z$, $L^2$ etc. And definitely they commute with the central potentials. Therefore we can say a lot of very useful information regarding the angular momentum regarding the spatial continuous symmetry.

I think I would give an example so you can guide me what I should be doing.

For a three dimensional isotropic harmonic oscillators we have energy levels $(k+l+3/2) \bar h \omega = (n+3/2) \bar h \omega  $. For different value of n, we can say about the different l value. We can also say if the electron would be in S, P, or D state. So we get very important physics from angular momentum.

Now let's move into the three-dimensional particle in a box, which is not central potential. Now If someone asks me that what angular momentum information (symmetry if any) we can have from this and how the study would be helpful regarding important physics?

Comment: Why would you want to use angular momentum operators when the potential is not spherically symmetric?  How would you deal with the Cartesian boundary conditions using angular momentum wavefunctions?

Comment: Angular momentum wave functions are written mostly in spherical coordinate system. I do not know how useful it would be if I want to transform them into cartesian coordinates?

Comment: nevermind useful.  Can you even satisfy the boundary conditions?

Comment: The wave function is zero in all  boundaries for the wave function in  certain coordinates. Is that what you said?

Comment: If the quantum system is closed in a box and has an angular momentum, then perhaps this means that the box is spinning. The most common case is the rotation of the box as a whole around a certain axis with an angular velocity  $\vec {\Omega}$. In a rotating coordinate system, the Schrödinger equation in various versions in the linear and nonlinear case has been studied by many authors.

Comment: Note that if your box is spherical (instead of cubic), then the potential is central, and angular momentum is conserved.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have experience in modeling quantum vorticity in a condensate, I will present here some general principles and give examples. Usually we use a rotating coordinate system and there we investigate the problem, for example, we find eigenfunctions. Then the boundary conditions can be fixed. Consider the problem of determining the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Schrödinger equation in a rotating cube with zero boundary conditions on the surface of the cube. The Schrödinger equation in a rotating coordinate system has the form (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07570v1 and https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0305081):
$$i\hbar \partial _t \psi=\frac {1}{2m}(-i\hbar \nabla -m\vec {A})^2\psi -\frac {m}{2}(\vec {A})^2\psi$$
Here $\vec {A}=R\dot {R}^T\vec {r}$, $R$ there is a rotation matrix. In the case of rotation with a constant angular velocity, we have $\vec {A}=\vec {\Omega}\times \vec{r}$. Then we get
$$i\hbar \partial _t \psi=-\frac {\hbar ^2}{2m}\nabla ^2\psi+i\hbar (\vec {\Omega}\times \vec{r}).\nabla \psi $$
Finally, choosing the z-axis in the direction of the rotation axis, we  find
$$i\hbar \partial _t \psi=-\frac {\hbar ^2}{2m}\nabla ^2\psi+i\hbar \Omega(x\partial _y-y\partial _x )\psi $$
We use this equation to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. It is necessary to choose the orientation of the cube relative to the axis of rotation. The simplest thing is if the axis of rotation coincides with the axis of symmetry of the cube passing through opposite faces. Put $\hbar=1$ and cube size $L=2$ then the first eight eigenvalues have the form (the magnitude of the wave function is shown, the eigenvalues are indicated above)
[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score -1):

The angular momentum is a useful quantity if it is conserved. If angular momentum is not conserved, then is does not help much to try and identify angular momentum eigen states.

It all comes down to the symmetries of the system, ala [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). Angular momentum is related to rotational symmetry. A box is not rotationally symmetric. Hence, angular momentum is not conserved. It means that the rotation operator would not commute with the Hamiltonian and therefore these two operators do not shared the same eigen states.

In a physical system that does not have rotational symmetry, the fields inside the system would exchange angular momentum with the boundaries. For instance, when light is reflected off a boundary, there is an exchange of momentum between the light and the boundary. If the momentum that is picked up by the boundary is not parallel to the position vector, then their cross product would be non-zero, leading to a nonzero angular momentum acquired by the boundary. For that reason, angular momentum of the field inside the boundary would not be conserved.

Comment: I totally understand your answer, except "the fields inside the system would exchange angular momentum with the boundaries". Is it possible to give some mathematical insight?

Comment: @flippiefanus The angular momentum is conserved regardless of the symmetry of the trapping potential (box or something else).

Comment: @AlexTrounev: That would only be the case if the box is treated is a dynamical part of the system so that one can add the angular momentum that is picked up by the box.

Comment: I added a bit more about the exchange of angular momentum.

Comment: @flippiefanus In the case of a space-limited closed system, one can always assume that the system as a whole rotates and that the angular momentum is conserved. Then, in the case of a particle in a box, the wave function is determined taking into account this restriction.

Comment: *If angular momentum is not conserved, then is does not help much to try and identify angular momentum eigen states.* I'm not sure if I fully buy this. There isn't even a "conservation of position", yet we use this operator all of the time to analyze quantum systems. Even when $X$ doesn't commute with $H$ we still use the position basis for certain systems.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: True, that would give you angular momentum conservation. However, this is not how it is usually done. The context of the OP question seems to imply that the boundaries are fixed.

Comment: @AaronStevens: That is not entirely correct. The position operator is not well defined for optical fields. In those cases where we do use a position basis, it is not related to a position operator. It is purely a coordinate basis.

Comment: @flippiefanus Usually we use a rotating coordinate system. Then the boundary conditions can be fixed.

Comment: @AlexTrounev you seem to be fixed on your particular case of vorticity in a condensate, where it does make sense to use rotating frame. But consider a cubic quantum dot embedded in a bulk semiconductor. In this case you won't benefit from a rotating frame, unless the semiconductor rotates as a whole.

Comment: I didn't say anything about optical fields.